# Xcode creates Outlet, but they aren't connected to the UI-elements

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I try to connect an UI-element to an outlet the standard way.

[image]

But afterward there's no connection between the outlet and the element. Please pay attention to the circle on the left.

[image]

What is going wrong here?

**How can the issue become fixed?**

Comment: How exactly do you create an outlet? What does your IB show in the Oulets section for this view?

Comment: @lazarevzubov Click on the UIImageView with ctrl-Key pressed. Then drag the line to the Swift-code on the right. Drop it there. Name the outlet in the appearing overlay.

Comment: There's a mismatch here: you're dragging to the code for a class called ImageViewCell, but your Object in the overlay is called ImageFrame. What is ImageFrame?

Comment: Also: Do you see the red arrow to the right of View Controller Scene? That says something is wrong with your setup in the storyboard for this scene. I would suggest that you fix whatever is wrong first, before doing anything else; I wouldn't expect _anything_ to work right if your scene is invalid in some way.

Comment: Do you have errors when compiling the App? I have this issue as well, with two connected Outlets, but everything works fine, they are just not marked as they should (with the little point inside). It might be related to a problem within XCode. You could address this to Apple support, so they can correct it.

Comment: Final point: Instead of control-dragging from the image view, a better bet is always to control-click on the _name of interface object_ in the document outline (on the left in your screen shot), without dragging, just to make the HUD appear, and in the HUD that appears, drag from the New Referencing Outlet to the code.

Comment: Final final point! Try restarting the computer. Sometimes Xcode simply gets wedged in some way and restarting helps it.

Comment: @matt "There's a mismatch here: you're dragging to the code for a class called ImageViewCell, but your Object in the overlay is called ImageFrame." You were right. I had messed up the naming.

Comment: If someone faces a similar problem: Check the Identifier and the Custom Class-name in Xcode. And the "withReuseIdentifier"-argument of UICollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(). @matt Thanks a big bunch for your help.

Comment: If the problem is solved, add an Answer or delete the question. Thanks.